# rxweb I am not able to do patchvalue for attributes of a formgroup

Tags: angular

My form has array of checkboxes. I want to display it in edit mode. I am trying to do patch value for the checkbox array but it do not work.

```
this.get<Array<mycheckboxmodel>>({ path: 'api/myAPICall/1?CompanyId=123', queryParams: [] }).subscribe(t => {              
            let arrDesg = this.bindCheckboxArray(t);
            this.myFormGroup.controls.checkboxArray.patchValue(arrDesg);       
            this.showDesignationsComponent = true;
        },() => {

        });
```

bindCheckboxArray function manipulates array to merge lookup and checkbox selected values in one array

Comment: It will be better if you could provide stackblitz of your above use case